# How to show result by echo after running the http url in browser

Tags: php, mysql, http, url

i am using below code to show the data in browser..but getting reply this

Resource id #4Resource id #4

```
<?php
define('DB_HOST', 'localhost');
define('DB_NAME', 'sazal');
define('DB_USER','root');
define('DB_PASSWORD','');
$myname=$_GET["name"];
$mycity=$_GET["city"];
//$userid=$_GET["userid"];
//$password=$_GET["password"];
//if ($userid="sa" && $password="123")
//{
if (empty($_GET["name"] && $_GET["city"])){
echo "0" ;
}
$myname=urldecode($myname);
$mycity=urldecode($mycity);
$con=mysql_connect(DB_HOST,DB_USER,DB_PASSWORD) or die("Failed to connect to MySQL: " . mysql_error());
$db=mysql_select_db(DB_NAME,$con) or die("Failed to connect to MySQL: " . mysql_error());
$sql="select * from tbl_sazal ";
$result = mysql_query($sql, $con);
echo "$result";
?>
```

i am running below http url

```
http://localhost/testurl/select.php?name=sazal&city=dhaka
```

Comment: You're getting that output because it is a `resource`. If your intent is to get those values that you have selected, you need to fetch results. and c'mon now, stop using that old deprecated API, use mysqli or PDO instead.

Comment: `mysql_` functions are depricated. Use `mysqli_` or pdo.

Comment: what has this got to do with java?

Comment: Use this function for result: `mysql_fetch_assoc($result)`

Comment: @soroushgholamzadeh..thanks for your reply...now i am getting below reply ArrayResource id #4    i am using this way                  $result = mysql_query($sql, $con);
$result1= mysql_fetch_assoc($result);
echo "$result1";

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$sql="select * from tbl_sazal ";
$result = mysql_query($sql, $con);

while($raw  = mysql_fetch_array($result))
{

  echo $raw['FieldName'];

}
```

update part of your code with above code, replace 'FieldName' with mysql table field name

Comment: ..thanks u much...really helpful for me ..now output it is ahemddhakasazal ahemddhakasazal ahemddhaka%testsazalkkk...but i want to differentiate every row data by | this sign...